# call backbone view function from jquery ui modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, jquery-ui-dialog

```
MyPage.Views.Content = Backbone.View.extend({
    loadPage: function() {
        //populate jquery grid
    }

    addUserPhoto:function(){
        //open jquery ui modal form where user can 
        //upload image. 
    }
})
```

jquery ui dialog on closing

```
$('#dialog').html('');
$('#dialog').dialog('close');
```

i want to call the `loadPage` function when the jquery ui dialog closes. I tried this

```
addUserPhoto:function(){
    //open jquery ui modal form where user can 
    //upload image. 

    //close dialog
    this.loadPage();
}
```

but that did not call the `loadPage` function.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close), you can specify a callback for the `close` event when you instantiate the dialog plug-in.

```
addUserPhoto:function(){

    var self = this;

    // Specify a callback for the dialog close event 
    // when you instantiate the plug-in
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        close: function(event, ui) {
            // Load page on dialog close
            self.loadPage();
        }
    });
}
```